# What will happen if we try to reconstruct signal using phase only or magnitude only?

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation, spectral-theory, signal-processing

I am studying Fourier Transform and it's inverse. We get phase and magnitude from Fourier transform and reconstruct it back from **both together**

My question is that

> 1. What will happen if we try to  **reconstruct** given signal back using it's **magnitude only** with any random phase values?
> 2. What will happen if we try to **reconstruct** given signal back using it's **phase only** with any random magnitude values?

Answer (score 2):

Not in general.

A set of conditions is given in this [paper](http://www.rle.mit.edu/dspg/documents/signrecons_1980.pdf): 
Hayes, Monson H., Jae S. Lim, and Alan V. Oppenheim. "Signal reconstruction from phase or magnitude." Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing, IEEE Transactions on 28.6 (1980): 672-680.